# Order of Predictors in R Neuralnet formula

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am having trouble understanding why the order of predictors in the formula of the `nn` function of `R` `neuralnet` package changes the resulting network. Here is a reproducible example with 2 inputs, and a categorical output.

**Initialization of the data**

```
set.seed(1)
density=runif(100,0,1)
residual.sugar=runif(100,0,1)
quality=round(runif(100,0,1))
```

**Constructing the data frame**

```
mydata=data.frame(density, residual.sugar, quality)
```

**First neural network. Notice the order of predictors - `density` first then `residual sugar`**

```
set.seed(3)
nn<-neuralnet(quality~density+residual.sugar, linear.output=FALSE, 
hidden=2, data=mydata, act.fct="logistic", rep=1)
plot(nn)
```

**Second neural network. Notice that I changed the order of predictors - now `residual sugar` comes first followed by `density`**

```
set.seed(3)
nn<-neuralnet(quality~residual.sugar+density, linear.output=FALSE, 
hidden=2, data=mydata, act.fct="logistic", rep=1)
plot(nn)
```

I expect the 2 runs of the `nn` function to produce networks that are equivalent to each other, in other words I expect that although the weights and biases would swap on the network - the error and the number of steps that it takes for the network to converge should be identical. However, as you will see when you run the above code the 2 networks are drastically different. Why?

Comment: Cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57129761/order-of-predictors-in-r-neuralnet-formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the seed means that the random initializations for the weights are fixed between the two models. However, changing the order of the features changes which feature is assigned to which weights. This means that even though the weight matrices are the same, you have two different models, and the update procedures will be different.

Let's consider an example. Suppose that in both models, a weight matrix is initialized as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.13 & 0.12 \\
0.29 & -0.37
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For the first model, the output of the affine transformation for that unit is given by

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.13 & 0.12 \\
0.29 & -0.37
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{density}\\
\text{residual sugar}
\end{bmatrix} + \text{bias}.
$$
However, for the second model the output of the affine transformation is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.13 & 0.12 \\
0.29 & -0.37
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\text{residual sugar} \\
\text{density}
\end{bmatrix} + \text{bias}.
$$
which is clearly a different result whenever $\text{residual sugar} \neq \text{density}$. This difference in result means that the backpropagation will produce different results between the two models, and therefore the weight updates will be different between the two models.

Neural networks are well-known to be non-convex optimization problems, so it's not surprising that the optimization does not recover the same solutions between the two models. Because of the non-convexity of the model, there are many weight configurations which will have the same loss value.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense. Sorry I am not "allowed" to give you +1 due to being a new member.

Comment: Once you have enough reputation, you'll be able to +1. You are always able to accept answers by clicking the check mark; however, you may wish to wait some period of time (perhaps 24 hours) before doing so just in case someone else comes by and writes a better answer.